# For Google Analytics, Is there any way to see all my web property's data in a single table?

Tags: google-analytics

I have set up a lot of web properties for different websites.

Is there any way that I can see all the brief data of those properties in one table?

For example:

```
GA_ID    |   Unique Visits    |   Avg. Duration  |
UA-1234-1|    1,661           |    00:37         |
UA-1234-2|    5,862           |    01:11         |
UA-1234-3|    2,707           |    04:33         |
UA-4567-1|    3,488           |    01:56         |
UA-4567-2|      719           |    02:41         |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way that i could think of that you could do this would be to use the Google analytics api.  It would allow you to request the data you need for all of the views you have access to.

The google analytics website will only allow you to analyse across a single view you cant create reports across views.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend setting up a Google Sheet with Google Analytics Add-on. Create report for all of the web properties and schedule reporting. Then you can create a new sheet called "Summary" that pulls all the data from the new sheets.

Comment: Any further tutorials for this? Thanks

Comment: I recommend starting here https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/google-analytics-spreadsheet-add-on.  It should be straightforward once you install the add-on. Let me know if you need further help.